Disabling laptop's built-in touchpad and keyboard during boot, before the display manager starts
My laptop's built-in touchpad and keyboard are malfunctioning and I'm currently using the USB touchpad and keyboard instead. I'm looking for a way to disable the built-in touchpad and keyboard even before the display manager starts. Ideally, I'd especially like my built-in keyboard to be disabled before the splash screen kicks in so it does not spam F12, flashing the screen between the splash screen and the boot messages (if that are what they are called).
I've looked around for similar questions, but all answers I could find use xinput disable, xinput float or edit Xorg configuration files. From my understanding, these methods rely on X server being already started by the Display Manager, which is already after the boot process.
I'm pretty much still new in the world of Linux, so if I misunderstood anything somewhere, please let me know!
Version details: Debian 12, xorg 1:7.7+23, xserver-xorg 1:7.7+23, kernel version 6.1.0-21-amd64, lightdm 1.26.0-8
